Uploading to TestFlight using Fastlane issue
In continuation to this question
I keep getting the below error when trying to upload to TestFlight: (please bare in mind that the key is indeed correct)
[08:17:35]: Called from Fastfile at line 30
[08:17:35]: ```
[08:17:35]:     28: 
[08:17:35]:     29:     # Upload the build to TestFlight
[08:17:35]:  => 30:     pilot( api_key_path: "fastlane/api.json" )
[08:17:35]:     31:   end
[08:17:35]:     32: end
[08:17:35]: ```
[08:17:35]: Authentication credentials are missing or invalid. - Provide a properly configured and signed bearer token, and make sure that it has not expired. Learn more about Generating Tokens for API Requests 

my json format is like so (bare in mind the multiple \n used for each line in the private key):
{
  "key_id": "my_key_id",
  "issuer_id": "my_issuer_id",
  "key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIGTAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBHknlhdlYdLu\nAgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBHknlhdlYdLu\nAgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBHknlhdlYdLu\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----",
  "duration": 1200,
  "in_house": false
}

and I provide the above api.json like so in fastfile:
pilot( api_key_path: "fastlane/api.json" )
Workflow yml file:
name: iOS Build and Upload to TestFlight

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build-ios:
    runs-on: macos-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Ruby
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: '3.3'

      # Install Bundler and CocoaPods
      - name: Install Bundler and CocoaPods
        run: |
          gem install bundler
          sudo gem install cocoapods

      - name: Install Node.js dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: Navigate to iOS directory, clean Pods, and remove Podfile.lock
        run: |
          cd ios
          pod deintegrate
          rm -rf Podfile.lock
          npx pod-install

      - name: Install Fastlane dependencies
        run: |
          cd ios
          bundle install
         
      - name: Decode and set up iOS certificate
        run: |
          echo "${{ secrets.IOS_DISTRIBUTION_CREDENTIALS }}" | base64 --decode > ios_distribution.p12
          echo "${{ secrets.PROVISIONING_PROFILE }}" | base64 --decode > provisioning.mobileprovision
        shell: bash

      - name: Import certificate to keychain
        run: |
          security create-keychain -p "" build.keychain
          security import ios_distribution.p12 -k build.keychain -P "${{ secrets.P12_PASSWORD }}" -T /usr/bin/codesign
          security set-keychain-settings build.keychain
          security unlock-keychain -p "" build.keychain
          security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple: -s -k "" build.keychain
          security list-keychains -d user -s build.keychain $(security list-keychains -d user | tr -d '"')
          security list-keychains -s build.keychain
        shell: bash

      - name: Set provisioning profile
        run: |
          mkdir -p ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles
          cp provisioning.mobileprovision ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/
        shell: bash
      
      - name: Build and upload to TestFlight
        run: |
          cd ios
          bundle exec fastlane beta

Fastfile:
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do
  desc "Push a new beta build to TestFlight"
  lane :beta do
    # Increment build number automatically
    increment_build_number(
      xcodeproj: "someapp.xcodeproj"
    )

    # Build the app using your specific workspace and scheme
    build_app(
      workspace: "someapp.xcworkspace",
      scheme: "someappQA",
      export_method: "app-store",
      export_options: {
        provisioningProfiles: {
          "com.someapp.app.qa" => "com.someapp.app.qa"
        }
      }
    )  

    # Upload the build to TestFlight
    upload_to_testflight( api_key_path: "fastlane/api.json" )
  end
end


To answer my own question, as I previously mentioned I was indeed using the correct key_id, issuer_id, and key - however, I was not signing the JWT (JSON Web Token).
I was under the impression that by just providing the key_id, issuer_id, and key would work but it seems that you first need to sign the token using the private key (.p12 file), then encode the whole json file with the below structure:
{
  "key_id": "<your_key_id>",
  "issuer_id": "<your_issuer_id>",
  "key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n<your_key>\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"
}

Further read on the above can be found on the following link: Generating Tokens for API Requests.
I've also made some small changes to my workflow file (your mileage may vary here since your project might be different) but the whole AppStore authentication part should clear things up.
GitHub Workflow file:
name: iOS Build and Upload to TestFlight
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build-ios:
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Ruby
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: 3.3

      - name: Install Bundler and Cocoapods
        run: |
          rm -rf vendor/bundle
          rm -f Gemfile.lock
          gem install bundler
          gem install cocoapods
      - name: Install Node.js dependencies
        run: |
          npm install
      # Update Cocoapods and resolve dependencies
      - name: Install Pods and update specs
        working-directory: ./ios
        run: |
          rm -f Podfile.lock
          bundle install
          bundle exec pod install --repo-update
      # Clean up before the build to avoid conflicts
      - name: Clean up derived data and caches
        run: |
          xcodebuild clean -workspace ios/mywork.xcworkspace -scheme myscheme -configuration Debug
          rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
      - name: Select Xcode version
        run: sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode_16.1.app

      - name: Decode and set up iOS certificate
        shell: bash
        run: |
          # Decode the iOS distribution certificate and provisioning profile from secrets
          echo "${{ secrets.IOS_DISTRIBUTION_CREDENTIALS }}" | base64 --decode > ios_distribution.p12
          echo "${{ secrets.PROVISIONING_PROFILE }}" | base64 --decode > provisioning.mobileprovision
      - name: Check OpenSSL version
        run: openssl version

      - name: Import certificate to keychain
        shell: bash
        run: |
          # Create a new keychain and import the decoded certificate
          security create-keychain -p "" build.keychain
          security import ios_distribution.p12 -k build.keychain -P "${{ secrets.P12_PASSWORD }}" -T /usr/bin/codesign
          # Make sure the keychain is unlocked and accessible
          security set-keychain-settings build.keychain
          security unlock-keychain -p "" build.keychain
          # Allow codesign to access the key in the keychain without prompting for permissions
          security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple: -s -k "" build.keychain
          # Add the new keychain to the list of keychains searched by codesign
          security list-keychains -d user -s build.keychain $(security list-keychains -d user | tr -d '"')
      - name: Set provisioning profile
        shell: bash
        run: |
          # Create the provisioning profile directory if it doesn't exist and copy the profile
          mkdir -p ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles
          cp provisioning.mobileprovision ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/
      - name: Decode Base64 App Store Connect API key
        working-directory: ./ios
        shell: bash
        run: |
          echo "${{ secrets.APPSTORE_API_KEY_JSON_BASE64 }}" | base64 --decode | jq > ./AuthKey.json
      - name: Check AuthKey.json contents
        working-directory: ./ios
        shell: bash
        run: |
          cat AuthKey.json
      - name: Validate AuthKey.json
        working-directory: ./ios
        shell: bash
        run: |
          jq '.' AuthKey.json
      - name: Build and upload to TestFlight
        working-directory: ./ios
        run: |
          bundle exec fastlane beta
        env:
          APP_STORE_CONNECT_API_KEY_PATH: AuthKey.json
          FASTLANE_USER: ${{ secrets.FASTLANE_USER }}
          FASTLANE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.FASTLANE_PASSWORD }}

FYI - Some of the above steps are not really needed and are just there for debugging purposes.

Could you please check this fasltane issue https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/21109 your insight might be important, could help solving the issue for many people.

@AhmadHamze thanks for pointing that out, I just commented my solution.
